# the "Back" button on devices does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The navigation itself works fine, but when I want to go back using the appropriate button on the phone, it doesn't. It feels like the code doesn't see that I'm pressing the button at all. Can you help me or explain why this problem occurs?
I use nesting navigation. It`s stack navigation and tab navigation

I prescribed the navigation as follows

```
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import Explore from '../components/screens/explore/Explore'
import Home from '../components/screens/home/Home'
import Language from '../components/screens/language/Language'
import Location from '../components/screens/location/Location'
import Search from '../components/screens/search/Search'
import Settings from '../components/screens/settings/Settings'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Location' component={Location} options={{ headerShown: true, headerShadowVisible: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Language' component={Language} options={{ headerShown: true, headerShadowVisible: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const Navigation: FC = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#F5F6F8',
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            height: 55
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeNavigation}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, color, focused }) => {
              const iconColor = focused ? '#1359BA' : '#596372'
              return (
                <Feather name='home' size={16} color={iconColor} style={{ marginBottom: -10 }} />
              )
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Explore"
          component={Explore}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, color, focused }) => {
              const iconColor = focused ? '#1359BA' : '#596372'
              return (
                <Feather name='compass' size={16} color={iconColor} style={{ marginBottom: -10 }} />
              )
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={Search}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, color, focused }) => {
              const iconColor = focused ? '#1359BA' : '#596372'
              return (
                <Feather name='search' size={16} color={iconColor} style={{ marginBottom: -10 }} />
              )
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={Settings}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, color, focused }) => {
              const iconColor = focused ? '#1359BA' : '#596372'
              return (
                <Feather name='settings' size={16} color={iconColor} style={{ marginBottom: -10 }} />
              )
            }
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default Navigation
```

Comment: From which screen you trying to go Back . In your code i see you only use TabNavigate.